# Splitting two channels of a WAV file into separate stereo files using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, wav, gopro

When activating RAW audio on a GoPro camera, you will get a WAV file with 4 channels. Channels 1 and two are the left and the right channel of the audio. Actually, I have no idea what channels 3 and 4 are doing. For me they are empty.
Now I want to have the channels 1 and 2 as dedicated WAV files even turned into a stereo format.
At the moment I achieved this with a two-step process using the ffmpeg command line tool like:
Splitting the channels into separate files

`ffmpeg -y -i source.wav -c pcm_s32le -filter_complex 'channelsplit=channel_layout=4.0[C1][C2][C3][C4]' -map '[C1]' channel1.wav -c pcm_s32le -map '[C2]' channel2.wav -map '[C3]' channel3.wav -map '[C4]' channel4.wav`

and then convert the mono files into stereo

`ffmpeg -y -i channel1.wav -c pcm_s32le -ac 2 channel1-stereo.wav`

**My question is now if I can do this in one step and even just ignore the two channels I don't care about?**

Right now I need to create temporary files for all four channels and then do a second step to convert the two channels I'm interested in into stereo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-ac 2` before each output filename.

`ffmpeg -y -i source.wav -filter_complex 'channelsplit=channel_layout=4.0[C1][C2][C3][C4]' -map '[C1]' -ac 2 -c pcm_s32le channel1.wav -map '[C2]' -ac 2 -c pcm_s32le channel2.wav -map '[C3]' -ac 2 -c pcm_s32le channel3.wav -map '[C4]' -ac 2 -c pcm_s32le channel4.wav`